# Resgistering photos issues in android programming

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am implementing an android app using camera to take pictures then  registering it in External_storage\Android\data\com.abc.projectname.bf . But after openning the camera , even if i don't capture , an image file is registered in the directory . How can i solve that , here is the code :

```
public void onCapturePhoto(String fileName){
    //Intent to take photos


    File storageDirectory = requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    try {
        Log.d("#picName",fileName);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(fileName,".jpg",storageDirectory);

            currentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Uri imageUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(),"com.ticanalyse.mheath.bf",imageFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            Log.d("#image_length is ",String.valueOf(imageFile.length()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //  imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
//            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
////            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
//            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
//            //Convert bitmap to byteArray
//            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
//            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
//            //Then convert to base64
//            encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
//            Log.d("#base64",encodedImage);


            //   setPic();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share related code for better reference?

Comment: @SujalKumar i found an alternative to the problem . but now if i  open the camera , then exit it , 0Mo file is registerd in the directory even if i didn't capture any photo . What problem can cause that ?

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing the code.

Comment: @SujalKumar , here is the code

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share the `onActivityResult()` as well? I think deleting the file if no action was taken could solve your issue and that has to be implemented in that method itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, have the **imageFile** object from this line:

```
File imageFile = File.createTempFile(fileName,".jpg",storageDirectory);
```

...declared as a global in the Activity like this...

```
public class XYZActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private File imageFile;
    //onCreate(), onCapturePhoto(), etc methods
}
```

Then in `onCapturePhoto()`:

```
imageFile = File.createTempFile(fileName,".jpg",storageDirectory);
```

Now in the `onActivityResult()`, if you ensure that no image was taken/clicked, you could try deleting the temporary file like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         //Your stuff...
    }
    else {
        //No photo was taken or clicked...
        //Thus, deleting the temporary file...
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (file.delete()) {
                Log.i("Process", "Deletion DONE!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I interpreted any part of problem in a undesirable way, please let me know.